# Как эффективно парсить query параметры в http запросе на сервере golang

Tags: golang, backend

Подскажите, как можно эффективно распарить query параметры, пришедшие на сервер Go в http запросе и записать их к примеру в struct или мапу.
Знаю как получать параметры по ключу через метод Get, но проблема в том, что их может приходить произвольное количество, а это уже куча проверок. Можно ли их записать в заготовленную структуру? На сервере не используются апи фреймворки, только маршрутизатор chi.

Answer (score 0):

прикладываю реальный код.
использовался пакет `"github.com/go-playground/form/v4"`

```
func NewMetricsHandler() (*MetricsHandler, error) {

    return &MetricsHandler{
        formDecoder: form.NewDecoder(),
    }, nil
}


type MetricsParams struct {
    MachineID    []string          `form:"machine_id"`
    Metrics      []string          `form:"metrics"`
    MetricWindow map[string]string `form:"window"`
    From         time.Time         `form:"from"`
    To           time.Time         `form:"to"`
    
}

func (handler *MetricsHandler) LastMetrics(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := new(MetricsParams)

    err := handler.formDecoder.Decode(params, r.URL.Query())
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }
...
```